# Merging view displays into same view

Tags: 7, views

I've got a view with 5 complex view displays (4 pages and 1 feed).

I've also got another view with 7 even more complex view displays which where automatically generated from the `calendar` module.

Is it possible to merge those 2 view displays into the same view? Or alternativelly execute `Add view from template` within an existing view. So the 7 `calendar` view displays ends up appended in the view which already contains my 5 custom view displays.

What I've tried so far:

- `Add view from template` in a new view and replicate/recreate by hand my custom 5 displays
- export the 2 views with `features` and try to merge the code so I can "features revert" to a single view

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd approach may be more trouble than it's worth, unless this is a learning exercise. As far as other options go, can't think of any, you may have to just recreate your displays.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

Simply cut/paste the display code from the views export of the first view and past it in to the 2nd view.

Make sure to change the display machine name if it overlaps with any of the display machine names in the 2nd view (example page_1).

Import this new, combined view.